# src/app.module.ts:6:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'adminjs' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: docker, nestjs, adminjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxjY2.png)

I have NestJs App with the docker, and i want to add AdminJs to it. I follow install guide and install everything, but when i compose it up it can not find the module, what can be a problem? on he img You can see that the module is there.

try docker-compose up
and get error src/app.module.ts:6:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'adminjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: Hello, going throught the same issue, installed the core package, installed @adminjs/nestjs but I am getting the same issue. 
`src/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts:18:12 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@adminjs/nestjs' or its corresponding type declarations.

18     import('@adminjs/nestjs').then(({ AdminModule }) => AdminModule.createAdminAsync({`

Comment: Is there any solution that is found? Even I am stuck with the same issue..

Comment: any solution i am facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear which guide did you follow to add AdminJS to your app. However, did you install the core package?

`yarn add adminjs` or `npm install adminjs`.

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.adminjs.co/installation/getting-started) for reference.